# F# assign value to a method argument

Tags: f#

I am trying to override a method provided by an interface/API and have to assign a new value to one of the method's argument. If I try to assign to the passed argument, it'll give an error.

```
override  _.Emit(eventInfo:SequenceStartEventInfo, emitter:IEmitter) = 
        eventInfo <- SequenceStartEventInfo(eventInfo.Source)
        [...]
```

I am looking for behavior matching the following C# code:

```
public override void Emit(SequenceStartEventInfo eventInfo, IEmitter emitter) {
        eventInfo = new SequenceStartEventInfo(eventInfo.Source)
        ...
}
```

If I change it and try to pass by reference (`eventInfo:byref<SequenceStartEventInfo>`) then it'll no longer match the available overloads.

The F# language reference on parameters and methods doesn't provide any help when dealing with this specific case. What is the best way to handle this Scenario?

Comment: Why does it have to be the argument variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C# you can assign a new value to the argument *variable*, but as it is not passed by reference, this won't change the variable of the caller (even though the passed object is a reference type):

```
public static void Main()
{
    var rt = new RefType { Value = 3 };
    Change(rt);
    Console.WriteLine(rt.Value); // still 3
}

public class RefType {
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

public static void Change(RefType notByRef){
    notByRef = new RefType { Value = 42 };
}
```

the F# equivalent (where parameters are immutable) would be [shadowing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/functions/#scope):

```
type RefType() =
    member val Value = 0 with get, set

let Change notByRef =
    let notByRef = RefType(Value = 42);
    // now, `notByRef` hides the method parameter
    ()

let [<EntryPoint>] Main _ =
    let rt = RefType(Value = 3);
    Change(rt);
    printfn "%i" rt.Value // still 3
    0
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about the value/reference semantics, and made an error reading the relevant API's documentation missing the part where the relevant variable was passed to another method.